# Versioning objects in hazelcast

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

Apologies in advance, this is my first time asking questions here.

Here is hazelcastInstance bean.

The main problem is - a class is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation

```
    @Bean
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastSessionInstance() {

    if ("embedded".equalsIgnoreCase(hazelcastType)) {
        return new HazelcastEmbeddedSessionBuilder(hazelcastSessionSettings).build();
    } else {
        return new HazelcastClientSessionBuilder(hazelcastSessionSettings)
                .addClass(MyTestDto.class)
                .addClass(SomeClass.class)
                .addClass(AnotherClass.class)
                .addClass(GameWeb.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I change type from embedded to another in application.yaml:

[here is settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19NAx.png)

I run the application everything works correctly, but if i add or remove any object in MyTestDto class and restart the application hazelcast starts throwing exceptions
saying that the bytecode of this class in the cache is different from the current one. In this case, either restarting the computer or renaming the class can help, this will clear the class cache. Here is the class from which all the trouble:

```
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class MyTestDto extends Details implements DataSerializable {
    private PrePrincipal prePrincipal;
    //test obj
    private String testStr = "asdtest";


    public MyTestDto(UUID testUId, UUID testId, String testString, Collection<String> testCollection, PrePrincipal prePrincipal) {
        super(testUId, testId, testString, testCollection);
        this.prePrincipal = prePrincipal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("testUId", getTestUId())
                .add("testId", geTestId())
                .add("testString", getTestString())
                .add("prePrincipal", prePrincipal)
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeString(testStr);
        out.writeObject(prePrincipal);
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        testStr = in.readString();
        prePrincipal = in.readObject();
    }
}
```

StackTrace

```
05.08.22 18:22:46.705 [restartedMain] S: R: U: O: C: A: ERROR o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatStarter - 
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean 
with name 'sessionUser' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionUser' 

parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastSessionInstance' defined in class path resource [org/example/game/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastSessionInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class org.example.game.MyTestDto is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation
05.08.22 18:22:46.728 [restartedMain] S: R: U: O: C: A: INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
05.08.22 18:22:46.738 [restartedMain] S: R: U: O: C: A: WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
05.08.22 18:22:46.751 [restartedMain] S: R: U: O: C: A: INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
05.08.22 18:22:46.774 [restartedMain] S: R: U: O: C: A: ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at org.example.game.GameApplication.main(GameApplication.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastSessionInstance' defined in class path resource [org/example/game/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastSessionInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class org.example.game.MyTestDto is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastSessionInstance' defined in class path resource [org/example/game/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastSessionInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class org.example.game.MyTestDto is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastSessionInstance' defined in class path resource [ru/revgames/game/auchan/match3/config/security/HttpSessionConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastSessionInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class org.example.game.MyTestDto is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2030)
    at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration.setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration.java:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastSessionInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class org.example.game.MyTestDto is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class org.example.game.MyTestDto is already in local cache and has conflicting byte code representation
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.defineClassFromClient(ClassLocator.java:123)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.defineClassesFromClient(ClassLocator.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.UserCodeDeploymentService.defineClasses(UserCodeDeploymentService.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.operation.DeployClassesOperation.run(DeployClassesOperation.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.call(Operation.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:272)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:213)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:411)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:438)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:600)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:579)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:540)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:240)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMultiTargetMessageTask.processInternal(AbstractMultiTargetMessageTask.java:70)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractAsyncMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractAsyncMessageTask.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:153)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:116)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
    at ------ submitted from ------.()
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.ExceptionUtil.cloneExceptionWithFixedAsyncStackTrace(ExceptionUtil.java:279)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.returnOrThrowWithGetConventions(InvocationFuture.java:112)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:95)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:40)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:617)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientUserCodeDeploymentService.deploy(ClientUserCodeDeploymentService.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.clientside.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.sendStateToCluster(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:865)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.clientside.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:413)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.constructHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:460)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClientInternal(HazelcastClient.java:416)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:136)
    at org.example.game.SessionBuilder.build(HazelcastClientSessionBuilder.java:52)
    at org.example.game.Config.hazelcastSessionInstance(HttpSessionConfig.java:65)
    at org.example.game.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3760279.CGLIB$hazelcastSessionInstance$2(<generated>)
    at org.example.game.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3760279$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4644b10b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.example.game.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3760279.hazelcastSessionInstance(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 100 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data model is going to evolve, you have three options.

Use [VersionedPortable](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/serialization/implementing-portable-serialization#versioning-for-portable-serialization), which allows for different versions of the object concurrently.

Use [CompactSerialization](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/serialization/compact-serialization#schema-evolution) which is a beta feature in 5.1, does essentially the same as the above but using less memory.

Use [JSON](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/serialization/serializing-json#hide-nav) which has no strong typing.